# Setting Auto_Increment to start from 1000 when creating table

Tags: mysql

I want my table's primary key to start from the number 1000 instead of the default. I read around here and the answer is to declare the increment value when creating the table as follows:

```
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

I tried it when I `CREATE` my table but it returns a syntax error. Of course I could make the changes on `PhpMyAdmin` but I want to do it on `CREATE` instead. Please advice what is wrong. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Departments
(
  Dept_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT=1000, -- the equals sign returns the syntax error. 
  Dept_Name varchar(255), 
  Dept_Address varchar(255), 
  Dept_Tel int,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dept_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting point must be specified as a table option:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Departments
(
  Dept_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  Dept_Name varchar(255), 
  Dept_Address varchar(255), 
  Dept_Tel int,
  PRIMARY KEY (Dept_ID)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

You can see the full syntax for creating a table [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)